# ActivityUnitTestCase lifecycle testing

Tags: android, lifecycle, activityunittestcase

I was unit testing a simple app today. I have a method

```
protected void onRestart() {
    disp.setText("The numbers you entered were");
    super.onRestart();
}
```

And in my test case i'm using

```
public void testRestart(){
    String dispText = disp.getText().toString();
    getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStop(mActivity);
    assertEquals(dispText, disp.getText().toString());
}
```

The assertion returns true meaning that the text isn't changed. However when i use

```
public void testRestart(){
    String dispText = disp.getText().toString();
    getInstrumentation().callActivityOnRestart(mActivity);
    assertEquals(dispText, disp.getText().toString());
}
```

the assertion is false as expected.

According to the activity lifecycle onRestart() should always be called after onStop() if the user navigates away from the activity.

Shouldn't the onRestart() method be called after onStop() ? Or does calling `getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStop(mActivity);` kill the activity, instead of just stopping it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ActivityUnitTestCase** is an isolated, *unit test* of a single **Activity**. The *Activity Under Test* does not participate of the system interactions.

You can start your **Activity** using `startActivity()`, and it will invoke `onCreate()`, however if you wish to further exercise **Activity** life cycle methods, you must call them yourself from your test case.

Comment: Ya i get that. My question is that are the lifecycle methods completely independent of each other ? Shouldn't calling `callActivityOnStop` call onStop() and then onRestart() ? Or does it just call onStop() only ?

Comment: In the case you mentioned, you must call lifecycle methods, so calling `onStop()` won't call `onRestart()`